# Linear algebra book revolved around modern day applications.

Tags: linear-algebra, book-recommendation, applications

As the title says, I'm looking for a book which describes the modern day applications of linear algebra. I already had an introductory course on linear algebra, so I'm specifically looking for the ways it can be applied to solve real world problems.

Comment: Gilbert Strang's book Linear Algebra contains a basic introduction for applications http://math.mit.edu/~gs/linearalgebra/ and a more deep discussion in Computational Science and Engineering http://math.mit.edu/~gs/cse/.

Comment: What books did you read in your intro class?